# Telegram-desktop via x2go won't start

Tags: x2go

Telegram-desktop via x2go won't start.

Host machine:

```
$ uname -r
4.17.14-arch1-1-ARCH
$ pacman -Qs openssh
local/openssh 7.7p1-2
$ pacman -Qs x2goserver
local/x2goserver 4.1.0.2-1
$ pacman -Qs telegram-desktop
local/telegram-desktop 1.3.10-2
```

Client machine:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$ x2goclient --version
x2go-INFO-1> "Starting X2Go Client 4.1.1.1..."
```

Telegram-desktop works just fine on the host (arch linux). However it won't start through x2goclient with session type XFCE.

```
$ telegram-desktop 
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-russ'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-russ'
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Gdk-Message: 10:56:30.756: telegram-desktop: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :132.0.
```

I tried different ways to start it.

```
$ XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000/ telegram-desktop
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Gdk-Message: 10:58:01.143: telegram-desktop: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :132.0.
$ XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000/ telegram-desktop -style Fusion 
Gdk-Message: 10:58:37.227: telegram-desktop: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :132.0.
```

Also tried to change the icon theme on the host machine, but no luck. Other apps works ok through x2go. Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

X2GO_NXAGENT_DEFAULT_OPTIONS+=" -extension BIG-REQUESTS"

comment out this line in /etc/x2go/nx_agent.options

There's a warning w/r to crashing when the option is enabled, so I'll have to keep an eye on that; Telegram works again nicely via x2go now, though.

All the best, uwe

Comment: hi! thanks for the reply. can't find /etc/x2go/nx_agent.options, i have only /etc/x2go/x2goagent.options and that line was commented out.